# How to integrate ReactJS with Redux and Spring mVC

Tags: spring, reactjs, redux, state

I am a newbiew of ReactJS. Before, I used ReactJS for my company's project but actually that project has configurated by somone. I just apply what I know about Reactjs into project such as : state, props, component, apply redux.....

But , now I want to create a project by myself step by step. In that I can use reactjs integrate redux to manage state for using data and Spring is server in RESTfull standard and combine with JPA

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate spring and react js using 2 approaches

- You can do it by making an isomorphic web app which uses nashorn engine(jdk8).
- You can use pusher api(I have used pusher api in my app)

As i can not explain the full working here,here are tutorials for reference
[using pusher api](https://blog.pusher.com/realtime-shopping-cart-with-java-and-react/) 
[isomorphic wb app](http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/02/16/isomorphic-react-webapps-on-the-jvm/)

Comment: Ok, tks very much....Did you heard about the library of restfull what is called fetch ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer.

You can use maven plugin https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin

Add to your pom.xml something like this

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>v4.4.5</nodeVersion>
                        <npmVersion>3.9.2</npmVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>webpack build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>webpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

and you need to add package.json like this

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "requirejs": "^2.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.22.0",
    "react-frame-component": "^0.6.6",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --progress --inline --hot",
    "build": "webpack -d"
  }
}
```

But list of dependenccies is yours

And you need webpack.config.js something like this

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var packageJSON = require('./package.json');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
              'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
              './src/main/resources/static/App.js'],
    devtool: 'sourcemaps',
    cache: true,
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './src/main/resources/static/built/bundle.js',
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/'
    },
    resolve: {extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']},
    plugins: [
               new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
               ,new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
                     debug: true
                   })
        ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: path.join(__dirname, '.'),
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    cacheDirectory: true,
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            },

        ]
    },
    devServer: {
            noInfo: false,
            quiet: false,
            lazy: false,
            watchOptions: {
                poll: true
           }
        }
};
```